# How to foreach inside script tag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

This is my code for my calendar :

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: false,
                events: [{
                    @foreach (var item in Model) {
                        title : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventName),
                        start : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate),
                        end : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

I have some trouble inside the foreach, the `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventName), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)`, and `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)` are underlined red, so I don't know what do I have to change or fix.
Thankyou.

Comment: Do you have a `@model` declaration at the top of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.Raw` should work for you in this scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: false,
            events: [{
                @foreach (var item in Model) {
                     @Html.Raw("title :"+item.EventName+",start :"+ item.StartDate+",end :"+ item.EndDate);                         
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably want a JSON object per array item, you'll need to emit a pair of {} braces for each item.  I've done this below with outer braces plus string.Join to emit the inner ones.  This will only work correctly if you have at least one item in the list.  Hopefully all my braces are matching up.  Beware with using Html.Raw that if users specify things like "EventName" they could embed malicious javascript, so you should take appropriate precautions to clean/encode those values if so.

```
events: 
   [
     @(Html.Raw("{" 
        + string.Join("},{", 
             Model.Select(m=> "title:\"" + m.EventName + "\",start:\"" + item.StartDate + "\",end:\"" + item.EndDate + "\"" ))     
        + "}" )
     )
   ]
```

Use your browser to inspect the generated HTML to see if you got the javascript you expected.